# Can Anti-aliasing be Disabled for a Drawable on an Android Canvas?

Tags: android, graphics

In my program I am trying to draw pixel art and don't want anti-aliasing to occur. I have found ways to disable anti-aliasing for [Bitmaps](http://www.41post.com/4241/programming/android-disabling-anti-aliasing-for-pixel-art) and [DrawableBitmaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) but not for [Drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). Is it impossible to disable anti-aliasing for Drawables?

I have tried the following:

```
drawable.setDither(false);
drawable.setFilterBitmap(false);
```

And as suggested by vmironov I tried to remove any filtering on the canvas like so:

```
DrawFilter filter = new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG, 0);

Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

canvas.setDrawFilter(filter);
```

This has a strange effect of removing anti-aliasing on my Toshiba Thrive but not on my Galaxy Nexus.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewLL7.jpg)

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable anti-aliasing for a whole [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) using [`PaintFlagsDrawFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PaintFlagsDrawFilter.html) and [`Canvas.setDrawFilter(DrawFilter filter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setDrawFilter(android.graphics.DrawFilter)) :

```
final DrawFilter filter = new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG, 0);
final Canvas canvas = ...;

canvas.setDrawFilter(filter);
```

**UPDATE:**

I've looked at the screenshots and I can definitely say it is not an anti-aliasing issue. What you see is a result of [`bilinear filtration`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) and unfortunately it can not be disabled for hardware accelerated views. As a workaround you can just use software rasterization for your view:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. I added some edits to my question with code and screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't appear to change the output 
`footballGameView.setLayerType(SurfaceView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`
I guess it still does linear interpolation with software. I dug into linear interpolation and couldn't find any help. Do you know if this issue would be independent to Drawables? If I can't fix this my next plan of action is to try bitmaps.

Comment: you can also try to move your images to `drawable-nodpi` folder